# how to load aplication from start up page each time in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have application for iphone i want to open it from start up page always but when i load first time app on ipad it loads from startup page but when i close app and second time run on ipad then it opens from the same screen from where i left i want that again it should open from startup page also.I have start up page with enter button when i click to button i move to calulations screen where i perform calculations .If i close on calculation screen the app when i again open it it opens from calculation screens not from the startup screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In plist file add one more field

Application does not run in background : make it true

This is your perfect ans.

Answer (score 1):

Second time app will be in Background thats why it is not starting with start app page. Dont allow application to run in background. Set  Key "" in info.plist file

Comment: i may  click on check box to clik or select mean its true for this

Comment: Yes you can set it to true/YES.

Comment: one thing i want to ask i have posted another question for change the random color and give particular color for each item in iphone graph

Comment: yes i have upvoted answer and please help me i am giving you another question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632887/how-to-giver-particular-color-for-each-item-line-in-graph-instead-of-random-colo

Comment: i dont have exprience with graph, ill try after few hrs.

Comment: DId you use core plot for graph?

Comment: no its not about graphs just for color change dear see the link instead of random color i have to set particular for each

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632887/how-to-giver-particular-color-for-each-item-line-in-graph-instead-of-random-colo

Answer (score 0):

You should add in your plist that property :

```
UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend
```

This will allow your application to "restart" instead of saving its state. This will allow you  to load the start up page each time.
([documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html))

Answer (score -1):

Well it is discouraged by apple , according to it's documentation:-

There is no API provided for gracefully terminating an iOS application.

In iOS,user presses the Home button to close applications. Should your application have conditions in which it cannot provide its intended function, the recommended approach is to display an alert for the user that indicates the nature of the problem and possible actions the user could take — turning on WiFi, enabling Location Services, etc. Allow the user to terminate the application at their own discretion.

Warning Do not call the exit function. Applications calling exit will appear to the user to have crashed, rather than performing a graceful termination and animating back to the Home screen.

Here's the [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1561.html) to it.Anyway nobody stops you from using 
`exit(0)` ,  but is discouraged.

Another way to do is is simply change your application's pList property `"Application does not run in background"` to true.